# Override React Native Style from Parent/Child Component

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

In React Native way, if I have this structure:

```js
function Component(props){
  return (
    <View style={props.style1}>
      <View style={{overflow: hidden}}>
        <View style={props.style2}></View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

How can I override the `{overflow: hidden}` on the 2nd View?
Let say that I don't have the capability to change the Component because I use a library that I don't have access to.

Answer (score 0):

You can override styles only if you have something like this

```js
export interface Props {
  extraStyle: ViewStyle
  }


function Component(props: Props){
  return (
    <View style={props.style1}>
      <View style={[ {overflow: visible}, props.extraStyle ]}>
        <View style={props.style2}></View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

and you have access to `extraStyle` prop outside, therefore if you define `extraStyle = {{overflow: 'auto'}}`, then it will be overridden. Otherwise, you cannot change its style from outside.